# Read encoded frames from audio file with ExtAudioFileSeek and ExtAudioFileRead

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

This is what I would like to do:

Get audio from the microphone

- Encode it in AAC, G.711 or G.726
- Write the encoded frames to a socket.

And this is how I'm trying to get there:

- I'm getting audio (PCM) from the microphone using [TheAmazingAudioEngine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/) and putting it in a buffer;
- Using [TPAACAudioConverter](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter) I'm reading audio from my buffer and writing to a temp file (AAC);
- In the processing thread of TPAACAudioConverter I replaced this:

  ```
  OSStatus status = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile, numFrames, &fillBufList);
  ```

  with this:

  ```
  OSStatus status = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile, numFrames, &fillBufList);

  UInt32 framesWritten = numFrames;
  totalFramesWritten += framesWritten;

  AudioBufferList readData;
  readData.mNumberBuffers = 1;

  ExtAudioFileSeek(destinationFile, totalFramesWritten - framesWritten);

  OSStatus readStatus = ExtAudioFileRead(destinationFile, &numFrames, &readData);

  ExtAudioFileSeek(destinationFile, totalFramesWritten);

  NSLog(@"Bytes read=%d", numFrames);
  ```

  but what I get is 0 numFrames read from file.

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong or any suggestion on alternative paths to achieve what I need?

Comment: I don't quite get what are you doing: writing to `destinationFile`, then immediately re-reading what you've just written?

Comment: From what I understand encoding happen on ExtAudioFileWrite so I'm trying to use this write/read loop to get the encoded data. This is one of different way I'm trying to achieve the goal exposed in the first part of the question and also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430805/get-audio-from-microphone-and-write-it-to-socket-on-ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned this approach and reused the AQRecorder class from the SpeakHere example by Apple.

The project is available here https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/SpeakHere.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that whatever ExtAudioFile does under the hood doesn't allow for seeking on a file that is open for writing.  If you look at the documentation for `ExtAudioFileSeek` it says "This function's behavior with files open for writing is currently undefined".

You can solve this by using the more extensible (and difficult) [Audio File Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/) and the [Audio Converter Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/) directly instead of the convenient Extended audio file services.