# Get audio from microphone and write it to socket on iOS

Tags: ios, audio

this is what I would like to do:

- Get audio from the microphone
- Encode it in AAC, G.711 or G.726
- Write the encoded frames to a socket.

I found many examples but they all write to file. Can you link me to any tutorial/documentation/example/library that has an output buffer or a callback instead?

Comment: I've found no publicly available documentation on such chain of tasks. Your _CoreAudio input callback_ would probably have to capture, take care of encoding and writing to a _circular buffer_ (instead of a file), which would be asynchronously read by the code for sending the data from buffer to the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by modifying the AQRecorder class from the SpeakHere example by Apple.

The project is available here https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/SpeakHere.